# How can I remap Ctrl+C to send an interrupt signal with another key?

Tags: bash, key-binding

I've got a process in bash that I can call to stop using Ctrl+C. As far as I can see, this equals to sending an exit(1) signal. I would like to loop through these processes for a list of different input files by typing the Escape key instead of Ctrl+C over and over. Here I am using ping on a list of URLs just as an example:

```
cat /tmp/file
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com
serverfault.com
programmers.stackexchange.com
```

How can I loop over the list and skip to the next by typing Escape instead of Ctrl+C?

```
cat /tmp/file | while read i; do ping $i; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stty to set the interrupt character.

```
stty intr q
```

Will set the interrupt character to your 'q' key. (I'm sorry, I'm not sure about the ESC code at this time). To set it back to CTRL+C, do:

```
stty intr ^C
```

Comment: Thx. I've asked for the Esc code in another question. http://superuser.com/questions/310418/how-can-i-redefine-the-interrupt-signal-to-escape-key