# how can I redefine the interrupt signal to Escape or Delete key?

Tags: bash

I've googled for it but failed to found an answer. I would like to remap my interrupt signal key from ^C to  or Delete, what would be the code for it? For example:

```
stty intr "ESC code"
```

And back:

```
stty intr ^C
```

Comment: maybe Delete would be better than Escape?

Comment: Indeed avilella

Comment: See [this SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/310333/) for the questioner's _real_ problem, which is to do with using the `ping` command against multiple hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do this. The character sequence generated by <kbd>Esc</kbd> is also used by the extended keys on the keyboard, so each keypress will be like pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> followed by some random characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
stty intr \033
```

This works somewhat, but since `\033`/Escape is used as, well, escape character, it'll break other stuff.

Comment: maybe Delete would be better than Escape?

Comment: Maybe not. It would drive you nuts editing the command line!